# How does spring initalise its beans?

Tags: java, spring

Say I have 2 beans: `A` and `B`.

`B` needs an `A` as a constructor parameter, and so is initialised after `A`.

Does spring map out the entire dependency hierarchy, and then starts initialising from the "leaves"? Or does it start to initialise `B`, then sees that it needs an `A`, and goes on to initialise `A`?

Maybe something else entirely?

Specifically, I'm asking in order to understand how code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39083480/2924784) works, and if in some cases it will include the time of the "leaf" beans inside the parent time.

Comment: perhaps this links explains it: https://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2014/05/05/The-DI-(IoC)-Container-Explained.aspx

Comment: not really, it explains the concept, but not the specific implementation that spring uses, and not specifically its effects on the `postProcessBeforeInitialization` and `postProcessAfterInitialization` of `BeanPostProcessor `

Comment: As stated in the official documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html The `postProcessBeforeInitialization` happens just after construction of the Bean and `postProcessAfterInitialization` just after any initialization, such as `@PostContruct`. 
I don't know the internal implementation, but the usual approach to IoC would be to check constructor `B` and see `A` is needed, and therefore initialize `A` first. But the initialization as noted in documentation of `A` will happen before `B` is called

Comment: Thank you. When you say "before `B` is called", you mean "before `postProcessBeforeInitialization` for `B` is called"?

Comment: I ran out of characters :) 
It would look at the constructor for `B` and see that it requires `A`, so it would put the construction of `B` on hold until `A` has been resolved. 
The Construction is before `postProcessBeforeInitialization`

Comment: thanks. want to put this as an answer?